# creating custom views without an extra view hierarchy

Tags: android

I usually create a custom view, for say,

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout{

  public MyView(Context context){
     super(context);

     //Inflating my custom layout
     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, this); 

  }

}
```

The problem with the above layout is, it will create a new `LinearLayout` and inflate `R.layout.view_layout` inside it, adding a new view hierarchy which is not preferred.

`R.layout.view_layout` contains `RelativeLayout` with many child elements, which I cannot add programatically by extending `RelativeLayout` (since positioning is difficult).

Having unnecessary hierarchies slow down my app.

What is the best way to create `custom views/view group` without an extra hierarchy level.

> **Solved as per the soln by CommonsWare:**

XML Layout:

```
<merge>

<TextView ...
.../>

More items

</merge>
```

Since the XML layout had `RelativeLayout` as the parent view, I will extend `RelativeLayout` in the code instead of `LinearLayout`

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{

      public MyView(Context context){
         super(context);

         //Inflating my custom layout
         LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, this); 

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have `res/layout/view_layout.xml` start with [a `<merge>` element](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) instead of a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I didn't fully understand this, although he use a `merge` tag in the xml, he still need a `RelativeLayout` inside the xml to keep the positions  of the child views, isn't?. So, if he extends from a `RelativeLayout` and uses a `RelativeLayout` inside the `merge` tag to keep the position, will be a duplicated hierarchy or not?

Comment: @astinx: Sorry, yes, I should have been more clear. The custom `View` should extend whatever the root container needs to be, and then the root element of the XML can be `<merge>` to avoid the duplicate container.

Comment: Yes exactly, I used merge in the xml layout and extending a viewgroup in the code. But still I don't see a lot of improvement

Answer (score 0):

`<merge>` is the solution but your layout is displayed incorrectly in Design mode in your IDE and this could be a pain. To fix this you need:

```
<merge
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"
    tools:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:layout_height="match_parent">
```